# Proper way of creating an observable with a meaningful pipe but meaningless content

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I'm creating an algorithm for displaying an alert/modal that prompts users to take action or be logged out of the application when he/she has been unactive for x amount of seconds, where x is lower than the timeout y on the refresh token.

How long the duration is calculated to be is irrelevant, but I'm solving the issue with RxJs.

I've reached the following pipe that seems to do the work:

```
this.countDown$
 .pipe(
   distinctUntilChanged(),
   switchMap(exp =>
     of(null).pipe(
       delay(AuthService.CalculateDelayTime(exp))
     )
   )
 )
 .subscribe(AuthService.TriggerModal);
```

`countDown$` is a `Subject<number>` that is continuously fed expiry time of the refresh token whenever route authentication is performed.

`CalculateDelayTime` and `TriggerModal` are both static methods (for now, as the modal itself has not been implemented; calculate returns an amount of seconds until the modal should appear).

Overall it seems to be what I want, but I'm a bit concerned of the `of(null)`. Is there a more correct/RxJs-style/elegant way to solve this specific problem? I do need the exp time for the delay-function, and I also want to reset the delay with each unique expirytime that comes in (which is why I use `switchMap`). 
However doing `of(exp)` suggests I am actually manipulating `exp` as a part of the inner pipe, which I am not.

I tried `Observable.empty()` but it seemed like the inner observable would not trigger.

Any suggestions how this should be done?

Comment: Any reason why `timer(AuthService.CalculateDelayTime(exp))` (i.e. returned by `switchMap`) wouldn't be suitable?

Comment: That does definitely seem like a good improvement!